# Sqoop job from python stdout=subprocess.pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqoop

I am trying to generate `Sqoop`command using `python`. I am able to pass and fire the `Sqoop` query. I wanted to map the column name in `Sqoop` command `--map-column-java` and number of columns are different in each column . only `BLOB` and `CLOB` needs to be `mapped`.

Data:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |
-----------------------------------------------
| C460                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C459                 | CLOB                 |
| C458                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C457                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C456                 | CLOB                 |
| C8                   | BLOB                 |
| C60901               | VARCHAR2             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

sample code :-

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(["sqoop", "eval", "--connect","jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + config["Production_host"]+":"+config["port"]+"/"+config['Production_SERVICE_NAME'],"--username", config["Production_User"], "--password", config["Production_Password"], "--query","SELECT column_name, data_type FROM all_tab_columns where table_name =" + "'"+ Tablename + "'"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
COl_Re=re.compile('(?m)(C\d+)(?=.+[CB]LOB)')
columns=COl_Re.findall(proc.stdout.read())
```

i am able to get the required column names`C459,C456,C8` using the above code . output `['C459', 'C456','C8']`

i should get a new `Sqoop` query with below format

```
sqoop import --connect  "--connect","jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + config["Production_host"]+":"+config["port"]+"/"+config['Production_SERVICE_NAME'],"--username", config["Production_User"], "--password", config["Production_Password"], --table table --fields-terminated-by '|' --map-column-java C456=String,C459=String,C8=String --hive-drop-import-delims --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N'   --as-textfile --target-dir <Location>  -m 1
```

i only need to add this part `--map-column-java C456=String,C459=String,C8=String` dynamically so that my next code `subprocess.call` can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Build your sqoop syntax by assigning to a variable and based on the conditions  override the variable with parameters and once the final syntax is built then execute it. Hope this helps.

Comment: it would be great if you can show some example . This much i have already did the RND.